How to indent bullet points inside a cell in a table in latex script?
I am trying to add a bullet point list inside a cell in a tabular format. Here what I have achieved so far;
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{11cm} p{3.5cm}}

    % Second multi-column entry
    {\rmfamily\scshape \textnormal{AAA}} &
    \textnormal{Some entry here} \newline 
    \textendash \textnormal{ Completed blablabla went to bla bla bla got to blablabla heeeey blablabla} & 
    \raggedleft \textnormal{Year} &

\end{tabular}

This code produces an outcome as such;

My issue with this output, as illustrated in the image above, is that I want to align the bullet point indent with the red line shown. How can I achieve this?

With the package enumitem?
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{11cm} p{3.5cm}}
  AAA&
  Some entry here
  \begin{itemize}[nosep,left=0pt,
    label=\textendash%<-- comment if you want bullet
    ]
    \item Completed blablabla went to bla bla bla got to blablabla heeeey blablabla
  \end{itemize}& 
  \raggedleft Year
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


